# Uploading text with multer

Tags: html, node.js, express, multer, body-parser

So i'm fairly new to programming and I apologize if my code is messy. What I am trying to do is make a website that people can upload a message and some photos/videos to. This is going to be used for my wedding and I want to be able to hand out the URL to people so that they can upload all the photos and videos they took, plus add a nice message. So far I have a running server that uses multer, express, and bodyParaser and i'm able to upload photos and videos but not the text that is typed in the "textarea". What am I missing that would allow what ever someone writes in the text area to be uploaded as a .txt file to the same folder that my photos and videos go into?

My file tree is set up like this: 
[Weddingupload_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDFpd.png)

**Front end HTML**

```
            <form style="text-align: center;" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

                <textarea class="textBox" name="message" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Share your favorite moment..."></textarea>

                <div id=uploadBtn>
                    <label class="uploadBtn">
                        <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" multiple accept="image/*,video/*,audio/*" />
                        Attach Images
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div id="submitBtn">
                    <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload Photo" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

**Server Side Code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const multerConfig = {
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function(req, file, next){
      next(null, './uploads/photos');
    },
     filename: function(req, file, next){
     console.log(file);
     const ext = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
     next(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.'+ext);
   }
 })
};

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.render('index.html');
   });

app.post('/upload', multer(multerConfig).array('photo'),function(req, res){
res.sendFile('public/second.html', {root: __dirname })
});

app.listen(port,function(){
console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);});
```

Comment: I know that this isn't necessarily in the scope you've outlined above, but have you considered introducing a nosql database like Mongo or Firebase to store each entry?

Another option would be writing to a single flat file every time someone posts to your server, with their message - and perhaps a name they input. 

My hunch on your original question is the user isn't uploading a text file, they are posting text, and you want to save it as a .txt file.

Comment: @jonnycraze, I have no knowledge when it comes to nosql,  Mongo or Firebase. That might be an option to try later on. But you are correct, I want what they type to be changed into a .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- edit index.html this is the text area with type="text"

`<textarea type="text" class="textBox" name="message" rows="10" cols="50"
                  placeholder="Share your favorite moment..."></textarea>`

- in App.js require fs and path

`const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');`

- update the destination function of the multer config to capture the text and create a text file.

`destination: function (req, file, next) {
      let text = req.body.message;
      let now = Date.now();
      fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, './uploads/' + file.originalname + '-' + now + '.txt'), text, console.log);
      next(null, './uploads');
    }`

Answer (score 1):

first add value="text" to textarea. and the text will be available on req.body.text 
then I would use "fs" module to create a text file with what you received.

Comment: Hey Netanel, how would I write the fs module? would i use the "fs.appendFile()" ?